# Image memory clean after i call GC.Collect() many time

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, bitmapimage

I am using the image to preview. after my work, I just set ImageSource to null and call GC.Collect() but after call GC.Collect() 50% memory is still on hold and its hold up to when I call again GC.Collect() ..

why it takes my call to clean?.

[image]

After Click Destroy

```
private void ImgDistry_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        image.Source = null;
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

After Destroy Image set image.Source = null, and call GC.Collect(); memory still on hold. it should be auto clean after some time.

[image]

and it holds memory until I call GC.Collect() 2-3 times after 15-30 seconds..how can i immediately clean unused bitmap memory?

Check Video(code and steps inside):- https://www.dropbox.com/s/457hhjnlttbzhlp/TinyTake%20by%20MangoApps-16-08-2018-06-28-51.mp4?dl=0

```
private void ImgDisplay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmap.EndInit();
            bitmap.Freeze();
        }
        image.Source = bitmap;
    }

    private void ImgDistry_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        image.Source = null;
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }

    private void ImgSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }
```

Comment: I can not (and do not want to) look at your video. Please give a detailed explanation of the expected and observed behavior, and the steps you take during observation. Are you probably stepping through the code in ImgDistry_Click with your debugger and wondering why memory isn't immediately released after Collect?

Comment: @Clemens yes my question is why is not immediately released after Collect and why it's waiting for another Collect call to release memory.. it should release immediately  or after some time ..

Comment: Probably because although you've set `image.Source = null`, the BitmapImage is still in use, because the Dispatcher didn't have time to update the Image element.

Comment: @Clemens ok so if Dispatcher didn't have time to update the Image element.. so it is in hold until I call again correct?. so what is the way to release memory immediately or auto release after some time?

Comment: @Clemens is this bug in WPF not cleaning bitmap image memory immediately?

Comment: @Clemens updated the question please take a look once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer.. need to update layout after set null to image source then call GC

```
private void ImgDistry_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        image.Source = null;
        UpdateLayout();
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
```